# Error when creating scheduled query on Bigquery "Error creating scheduled query: tq"

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks

What does this error imply? Am I missing a certain access or what?

Comment: you need to provide more details and some screen shots for better understanding of the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.